# Installed MuraCMS, now can't connect to Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, lucee, mura

I've installed Tomcat and Lucee and was able to see them running on localhost:8080.

I just installed the latest version of MuraCMS, and upon completing the installer it goes to a webpage (to finish the installation) but says it can't connect to the local server.

Now when I try to view the Tomcat and Lucee pages, they can't connect either!

Something in the Mura install broke my servers. Any help or ideas?

Comment: I doubt the Mura installer broke the server, maybe Tomcat stopped running for some reason, possibly out of memory or something similar. Try restarting Tomcat and checking the catalina.out for errors.

Comment: Checking now. I'm seeing this: "Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /usr/local/tomcat/lucee/lucee-inst.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM" --

Comment: See here: http://docs.lucee.org/guides/lucee-5/upgrading-lucee-45.html - point 2 under important information - Loading the lucee-inst.jar javaagent is no longer necessary and should be removed from your JVM arguments if you have it in place. (This could be in your Lucee dir at tomcat/bin/setenv.sh on *nix or tomcat/bin/service.bat on Windows.)

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: docs.lucee.org/guides/lucee-5/upgrading-lucee-45.html - point 2 under important information - Loading the lucee-inst.jar javaagent is no longer necessary and should be removed from your JVM arguments if you have it in place. (This could be in your Lucee dir at tomcat/bin/setenv.sh on *nix or tomcat/bin/service.bat on Windows.)